# SQL query to fetch distinct values from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, distinct

Let's say I have this table: employeetable:

| empid | joindate | location | HRupdatedate | Changes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2002-01-05 | Delhi | 2021-03-01 | New |
| 2 | 2009-09-09 | Mumbai | 2021-03-05 | New |
| 1 | 2010-06-27 | Hyderabad | 2021-03-03 | Transfer |
| 2 | 2015-11-02 | Delhi | 2021-03-06 | Transfer |
| 3 | 2020-01-01 | Mumbai | 2021-03-06 | New |
| 4 | 2007-07-30 | Delhi | 2021-03-04 | New |

I want to get data from this table where empid in (1,2,4). That will return:

| empid | joindate | location | HRupdatedate | Changes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2002-01-05 | Delhi | 2021-03-01 | New |
| 2 | 2009-09-09 | Mumbai | 2021-03-05 | New |
| 1 | 2010-06-27 | Hyderabad | 2021-03-03 | Transfer |
| 2 | 2015-11-02 | Delhi | 2021-03-06 | Transfer |
| 4 | 2007-07-30 | Delhi | 2021-03-04 | New |

But I only need the latest record without the duplicate entries:

| empid | joindate | location | HRupdatedate | Changes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2010-06-27 | Hyderabad | 2021-03-03 | Transfer |
| 2 | 2015-11-02 | Delhi | 2021-03-06 | Transfer |
| 4 | 2007-07-30 | Delhi | 2021-03-04 | New |

How to achieve this?

Comment: added tag for sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this by using `WHERE` clause.

```
select * from  
employeetable et1
where 
    joindate = (
        select max(joindate)
            from employeetable et2 
            where et1.empid = et2.empid
    ) 
    and 
    empid in (1,2, 4);
```

Or for more precise results

```
select * from  
employeetable et1
where 
    joindate = (
        select max(joindate)
            from employeetable et2 
            where et1.empid = et2.empid
    ) 
    and 
    HRupdatedate = (
        select max(HRupdatedate)
            from employeetable et2 where et1.empid = et2.empid
    )
    and 
    empid in (1,2, 4);
```

Comment: I compared it with the previous answer and found that using the second query you provided I can get the most recent data. Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `top with ties`

```
select top(1) with ties *
from employeetable
where empid in (1,2,4)
order by row_number() over(partition by empid order by joindate desc)
```

Comment: @RoseK . . . This is a convenient and clever solution.  But you should know that the performance is slightly worse than other solutions.